# UINavigationController with UITabViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, uitabview

I'm building an app which's delegate has a UINavigationController (navigationController). The first view is a UITabViewController (tabView) which has a UINavigationController with a UIViewController with a UITableView which shows some contacts.

What I want to do is to push a new viewcontroller with the contact's info when tapping over a contact in the tableview (over the toppest navController)

I do the following in the appDelegate:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
TabsView *tabsView = [[TabsView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[navigationController.view addSubview:[tabsView view]];
```

tabsView's first tab loads ContactsView.m which has a UINavigationController with all contacts and when someone clicks on one row, it is supposed to push the new view as this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    ContactSecondView * varContactSecondView = [[ContactSecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    varContactSecondView.title = [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:varContactSecondView animated:YES];
    [varContactMapView release];
}
```

But nothing happens when touching in a row.

So I have different files: Delegate with UINavigationController <- UITabViewController <- UIViewController with UINavigationController with UITableView; and I want to push a ViewController into the first navigationcontroller.

How is supposed to access to delegate's navigationController? Am I doing it right?

Edit: If this gives any clue, when I do `self.navigationController.title = @"Contacts";` in ContactsView.m, it's not changing the title of the topbar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. It is not recommended to embed a `UITabBarController` in a navigation controller.  It is ok to embed a UINavigationController within a `UITabBarController`.  I know it would be a "nice to have" to embed your `UITabBarController` in the `UINavigationController`, but you may want to rethink your design so that you follow the iOS design philosophy.
2. Instead of adding the subview to the window in your appDelegate, try adding which ever controller you are using to the window's rootViewController property i.e,

   self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;

Comment: Hi tim. Well, the problem is that the tabs makes the "content view" smaller, that was the idea of putting a uitabview inside a uinavigationcontroller. How is suppose to do this so? The second point didn't solve the problem yet :( Thanks!

Comment: The second point will not solve any problems, it is just the proper way of doing things.

Comment: OK. Forgetting about the NavigationController. If I have a navController in a tabviewcontroller. Is there any chance to hide the tabbar when pushing a uiviewcontroller? I've read about "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" but I don't know where exactly put it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think you don't use the correct way to set your view controller in your navigation controller.

You do :

```
[navigationController.view addSubview:[tabsView view]];
```

I would use :

```
[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tabsView] animated:NO];
```

Comment: Allright, I changed my code with yours but that's not solving my problem. It's still not pushing the new ViewController :/ Anything with didSelectedRowAtIndexPath? Thanks anyway!